# Is it possible to delete appstore from iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have searched for this answer for quite a while with no luck. Is it currently possible to remove the appstore from an iPhone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming. It would be more appropriate for https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: for what you need to delete Appstore ? Don' you want to use any applications ?

Comment: It was an odd test scenario that was invalid obviously.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.  Even on company controlled devices the App Store will still be present.  Using MDM (Mobile Device Management) you can control a lot about the phone, but the App Store is still present.

Answer (score -2):

Remove built-in Apple apps from the Home screen on your iOS 10 device or Apple Watch
With iOS 10, you can remove some built-in Apple apps from the Home screen on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Apple Watch.

When you remove a built-in app from your Home screen, you also remove any related user data and configuration files. This can affect things like related system functions or information on your Apple Watch.

The apps built into iOS are designed to be very space efficient, so all of them together use less than 200MB. Removing built-in iOS apps doesn't free up storage space on your device.

Built-in apps you can remove from your Home screen
If you have iOS 10, you can remove these apps from your Home screen:

Calculator
Calendar
Compass
Contacts1
FaceTime2
Find My Friends 
Home
iBooks3
iCloud Drive
iTunes Store
Mail
Maps3
Music3
News (where available)
Notes
Podcasts3
Reminders 
Stocks
Tips
Videos or TV
Voice Memos
Watch app4
Weather

If you remove the Contacts app, all of your contact information will remain in the Phone app.
If you remove the FaceTime app, you can still make and receive FaceTime calls in Contacts and the Phone app.
If you remove the iBooks, Maps, Music, or Podcast apps, they won’t be available to use with CarPlay.
If you try to remove the Watch app from an iPhone that’s paired with an Apple Watch, an alert asks you to unpair your Apple Watch before you can remove the app.

Remove a built-in app from your Home screen
On your iOS device, touch and hold the app lightly until it jiggles. If the app doesn't jiggle, make sure that you're not pressing too hard.
Tap Remove on the app, then tap Remove.
Press the Home button to finish.
If you have an Apple Watch, removing an app from your iPhone also removes that app from your Apple Watch.

Restore a built-in app that you removed
On your iOS device, go to the App Store.
Search for the app. Make sure that you use the exact name of the app. Find the correct name of built-in apps.
Tap  to restore the app.
Wait for the app to restore, then open it from your Home screen.
If you have an Apple Watch, restoring an app to your iPhone also restores that app to your Apple Watch.

What happens when you remove built-in apps from your Home screen
Removing built-in apps from your Home screen can affect other system functionalities. Here are some examples:

If you have an Apple Watch paired with your iPhone, removing an app from your iPhone Home screen also removes that app from your Apple Watch Home screen.
If you remove the Podcasts app from your Home screen, Podcasts won’t be available with CarPlay.
If you remove the Music app, you may be unable to play some audio content using Apple apps or third-party apps on some car stereos or stereo receivers.
If you remove the Stocks or Weather app from your Home screen, stocks and weather won’t be available elsewhere. For example, you won’t see stocks and weather information in Notification Center on your iPhone or as Complications or Glances on your Apple Watch.
If you remove the Calculator app, the calculator won’t appear in Control Center.